# ¿Viene realmente la palabra "sabadete" de "sábado" + "siete"?

Tags: etimología, historia

Leo en un [artículo de El País](https://elpais.com/elpais/2018/03/14/album/1521044858_543388.html):

> Si no sabías que en esta frase ["sábado sabadete, camisa nueva y polvete"] "sabadete" no es un diminutivo de sábado, no te fustigues. Aunque es lógico llegar a esa conclusión, esta vez la lógica nos tiende una trampa. En el siglo XVII "sabadete" surgió de juntar las palabras "sábado" y "siete" y hacía referencia a cualquier sábado que caía en día siete. Conjunción que se da dos veces al año y que según una superstición judía era idónea para dedicar esa jornada a elaborar polvos de talco.

He intentado buscar alguna referencia a esto, pero

- ni la palabra "sabadete" aparece en diccionarios pasados ni presentes,
- ni existen casos de "sabadete" en el CORDE, y
- los casos que aparecen en NGram y la hemeroteca de la BNE son del siglo XX, y hacen referencia al dicho "sábado sabadete".

Luego ¿en qué se ha basado el autor del artículo para afirmar eso? ¿Hay algún documento del siglo XVII o alrededores que haga alusión a este origen de "sabadete"?

Comment: Si sirve de algo, el número de veces que ocurra en el año es variable y puede ser entre uno y tres (promedio, 1,7). Me suena más a que quisieron aparentar que sabían

Comment: Curiosamente este sábado cae en 7 de julio.

Answer (score 6):

La fuente es este artículo **satírico** de [emitologias.com](http://emitologias.com) *("Explicaciones **mitológicas** para cotidianas expresiones")* de 2013:

> En el siglo XVII “sabadete” no era un diminutivo de “sábado” sino una palabra compuesta que se refería al “sábado siete”, o sea, cualquier sábado que cayera en el día 7 del mes. Según una superstición judía (Sabbath Setth) muy difundida en la época, esta conjunción (que se da unas dos veces al año), era propicia para preparar el polvo de talco, que adquiría mayores propiedades. Para celebrar este día, la tradición decía que médicos y farmacéuticos debían preparabar el talco con una camisa nueva. El significado sexual de la expresión llegó más tarde a raíz de la difusión del uso de polvo de talco por parte de las prostitutas.
>
> - [http://emitologias.com/2013/11/16/sabado-sabadete-camisa-nueva-y-polvete-origen/](https://web.archive.org/web/20140718035120/http://emitologias.com/2013/11/16/sabado-sabadete-camisa-nueva-y-polvete-origen/) (página archivada)

El sitio web original ya no existe, pero como dice [otro articulo](http://culturainquieta.com/es/inspiring/item/6000-sabado-sabadete-camisa-nueva-y-polvete-el-origen-de-la-expresion.html) citándolo:

> *No es una historia real, aunque bien podría serlo. Es un estupendo juego literario de [emitologías.com](http://emitologias.com/). También están en [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/emitologias?fref=ts)*

Comment: Si viene de la (afortunadamente) desaparecida emitologias.com entones se trata de una burda invención.

Comment: TL;DR: esta etimología es falsa.

Comment: por  lo menos en mi caso (no sé si aplica para otras personas), parece que se da explicación al origen de la quinta acepción de polvo en el DLE (coito)...